# IDE integration vs running standalone Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I've been always using the IDE Tomcat integration, where you just run a local Tomcat server through IDE (Intellij IDEA or Eclipse) to run your Java app. But now, some colleagues are claiming, that running a standalone Tomcat, or even Tomcat in a Docker container is actually better, because the configuration is not tied to your IDE.

That left me wondering, what are really the summed up advantages and disadvantages of either approach? Or is it basically the same thing?

Comment: Are you intending to put this application out into production somewhere? Presumably not running in your IDE?

Comment: Yes I am. The app will build after I push my commits to a Git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pros**:

- Developer see all required stuff in one single UI: logs, process status, etc
- IDE can support Hot Swap on compile
- IDE can automatically download and run tomcat for you. So you don't have to do this manually.

**Cons**:

- IDE can implicitly add some configuration or java-agents. It can make running process less understandable for developer.

**IMHO**:
Using IDE for running Tomcat (or any other server) is good if you understand what exactly the IDE does for you and how to run it without IDE. You should clearly understand why you run the Tomcat in IDE.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I asked. I want to understand the advantages clearly. Thank you, I appreciate it.